# Why does my Python function enter the else block when I use recursion to generate a Fibonacci list with 'else' in the if statement?

Tags: python, recursion

Recursion. The function returns a simple Fibonacci list in an approximate length.

We have a function that can work properly without the `else` block.
But confusingly, it also works correctly with an `else` block.

```
def sp_fibo_generation(length):
    if length <= 0:
        return [1]
    if length == 1:
        return [1, 1]
    else:              
        sp = sp_fibo_generation(length - 1)
        n = (sp[-1] + sp[-2])
        sp.append(n)
        return sp
```

Yes,  the code will work correctly without `else`. But why it does it work with `else`?

I tried to understand the principle of deep recursion.

Comment: Actually you are not trying to understand recursion here. You are trying to understand conditional branching (if-else). Please understand that first.

Comment: *"But why it works with else?"* - Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Because `return` exits the function. So if you fall off the second `if` and are still within the function, the `else:` is implicit anyway if you don't make it explicit.

Both styles are reasonably common, so I won't recommend one above the other; but you probably want to try to be consistent: Either change the second `if` to `elif`, or remove the final `else:` and remove the indentation from that block.